# MongoDB fails to start when auth is on

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits and I'm trying to install MongoDB.
I managed to do so by following the guide in the documentation [Installation Guide](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). Everything works fine until I want to active authentication. When I change /etc/mongod.conf with

```
auth=true
```

And I restart Mongo. It fails with error 111 and it never starts again, even though I have tried fixing permissions or other stuff I found online.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a log excerpt.

Comment: There is nothing on the logs that could tell something is wrong. All errors relate to permission errors.

Comment: Ok, in simple words : without facts, I can only guess. My guess is: you screwed permissions on the files and folders by running mongodb as root or sth similar. Please add additional information – you want the problem to be solved. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.